# Qt: Connect slot for a class defined within a QObject class

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals

I have class `MainWindow` that will contain several QWidgetTables with their own headers and other members. For now, I would like to define custom table classes within class `MainWindow` because they are pretty simple. See Example below:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(SSHClient &client, QWidget *parent = 0);

public slots:
    struct Workflow_Table {
        QTableWidget* widget;
        QStandardItemModel model;
        QStringList headers;

        void addRow(){}
        void removeRow(){}
    } workflow_table;


private:
    SSHClient& client;
    Ui::MainWindow* ui;

    CTL ctl;
};
```

Within `Ui::MainWindow` I have QPushButtons to add and remove rows for `workflow_table`. I would like to connect these `QPushButton::clicked` signals to 
`MainWindow::Workflow_Table::addRow`, but I haven't had any success, nor do I know if what I'm attemping is even possible.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(SSHClient &client, QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    client(client)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    //class CTL is a not a QObject class, yet std::bind causes it to act like a slot here. This statement compiles and runs fine.
    connect(ui->button_load_ctl, &QPushButton::clicked, this, std::bind(&CTL::saveas, &ctl, "saved.ctl"));

    //Error: 3 Arguments provided - 4 Expected. I'm almost certain this won't work.
    connect(ui->button_add, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::Workflow_Table::addRow);

    //Error: Not a signal or slot declaration. Not sure why this isn't working.
    connect(ui->button_add, &QPushButton::clicked, this, std::bind(&MainWindow::Workflow_Table::addRow, &workflow_table));

    //This doesn't work either. Error 1.
    connect(ui->button_add, &QPushButton::clicked, this, std::bind(&Workflow_Table::addRow, &workflow_table));

}
```

Is it possible that I can connect `MainWindow::Workflow_Table::addRow` (without making Workflow_Table a QObject) to a `QPushButton::clicked` signal from MainWindow?

The easy solution is to make `Workflow_Table` a QObject, but I'm curious if I can still connect the Workflow_Table's functions since they're defined under the scope of a QObject. I have been able to connect other non-slot functions by using std::bind like the `CTL::saveas` function so I would think I can do something similar here. I have also tried moving `Workflow_Table` under the `public` and `public slots` access specifiers but neither has worked.

Comment: the easiest way is to put `addRow()` inside `onPushButton_clicked()`. Using the Meta Object system is quite an overkill for just clicking and adding rows.

Answer (score -1):

It all works - it's your fault for not showing an actual, complete example that fails. When I paste it into an empty project, everything compiles except the second `connect`, there you have to use `std::bind` or a lambda so that the `addRow()` has something to work with.

Generally speaking, it's pointless to use `bind` if the lambda would be shorter, so just use lambdas when code clarity gains from it.

This works:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/connect-bind-44081724
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <functional>

class Class : public QWidget
{
   Q_OBJECT
   QPushButton button;
   struct CTL {
      void saveas(const QString &);
   } ctl;
   struct Workflow_Table {
       void addRow() {}
   } workflow_table;

public:
   Class() {
      connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, std::bind(&CTL::saveas, &ctl, "saved.ctl"));
      connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [this]{ workflow_table.addRow(); });
      connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, std::bind(&Workflow_Table::addRow, &workflow_table));

      // better yet
      connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [this]{ ctl.saveas("saved.ctl"); });
      connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [this]{ workflow_table.addRow(); });

      // or simply, if we know that `this` will outlive `button` (they do by design here),
      // and that both button and this live in the same thread (again, they do by design here)
      connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, [this]{ ctl.saveas("saved.ctl"); });
      connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, [this]{ workflow_table.addRow(); });
   }
};

int main() {}
#include "main.moc"
```